# How to clean up some data in a csv file using Powershell scripting and save the result as a new csv file?

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a csv (employees.csv) file of 3 columns contain `'n'` number of employee details and in my first column i have `employeeid` in a format `11_22$(contain integers and non integer values-string)` and here I want to remove all special characters and i want to keep only `1122(only integers)`.

In my second column I have their website address and is of format `www.website.com` and here i want to replace `www` by `http` that is i need `http.website.com`. In my third column i have their dob in format `YYYY:MM:DD` and i want to change it to `DD:MM:YYYY` format .
Finally i want to save/export the result to a new csv file. How can i achieve all these using PowerShell scripting?

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying to make work into the question. SO is not a free script writing service. If you need a programmer, you might try https://www.stackoverflowbusiness.com/talent

Comment: while RegEx solutions in javascript/PowerShell could look similar, you should choose which way to go and remove the other tag.

Answer (score 1):

Although i have no idea why you would want websites to become something like 'http.website.com' instead of 'http://website.com', you can do that using the code below.

```
########################################################################
# your input file 'employees.csv" looks like this
########################################################################

"employeeid","website","dob"
"11_22$","www.website.com","2000:04:12"
"22_33$","www.stackoverflow.com","1990:04:12"
"33_44$","www.somothersite.org","1970:04:12"


########################################################################
# after running the code the new file 'newemployees.csv' looks like this
########################################################################

"employeeid","website","dob"
"1122","http.website.com","12:04:2000"
"2233","http.stackoverflow.com","12:04:1990"
"3344","http.somothersite.org","12:04:1970"



$newcsv = @()
Import-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\employees.csv | ForEach-Object {
    $newcsv += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
        employeeid = $_.employeeid -replace '\D+', ''
        website = $_.website -replace 'www', 'http'
        dob = ([datetime]::ParseExact($_.dob, 'yyyy:MM:dd', [System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)).toString('dd:MM:yyyy')
    })
}
$newcsv | Export-Csv -Path $PSScriptRoot\newemployees.csv -Force -NoTypeInformation
```